# Network is unreachable after login

Tags: networking, wireless, login, internet

I have a weird problem: I'm using WiFi for my internet connection. It works flawlessly, until I decided to leave the computer for a while. When I come back, I login into it and unable to surf the internet. The WiFi/network icon remains the same (full connection), but when I try to ping a working internet address, I get `ping: connect: Network is unreachable`

Restarting networking.service with systemctl doesn't work. Disconnecting and then connecting once again to the WiFi hotspot solves the issue.

EDIT:
`sudo lshw -C network` output:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0f0
       version: 0e
       serial: 54:05:db:73:da:dd
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.8.0-41-generic latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:51 ioport:3400(size=256) memory:fd814000-fd814fff memory:fd800000-fd803fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 1a
       serial: 34:c9:3d:2b:a6:42
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-41-generic firmware=55.d9698065.0 cc-a0-55.ucode ip=10.0.0.28 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:102 memory:fd700000-fd703fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: enp5s0
       version: 15
       serial: 54:05:db:73:da:dc
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.8.0-41-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:69 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:fd504000-fd504fff memory:fd500000-fd503fff
```

How can I avoid this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: If chili555's solution doesn't work, can you update your question to include the output of `sudo lshw -C network`? This will contain network details that will make it easier for people to provide more specific support 

Comment: Sure, I have attached the output to the message. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your wireless may be dropping because of power management; that is, the feature where the wireless card partially powers down to save battery power during periods of inactivity and then, ideally, powers back up seamlessly when activity resumes. Let's disable power saving to see if it helps. From the terminal:

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
```

Is there any improvement?

Comment: Hi! thanks for replying. That didn't work unfortunately, I've logged in a few moments ago and had to restart the wifi connection

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see in the `lshw -C network` output, your machine is using the correct driver for that wireless card. So, let's see if we can build on chili555's answer with something a little more potent.

First, we will set the `power_save` mode for the card to `0` to prevent the network from being cycled down to `IDLE`, where it might get stuck:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Edit the `iwlwifi.conf` file as `root`:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
   ```
2. Add/Modify this line, ensuring the value is `0`:

   ```
   options iwlwifi power_save=0
   ```

   Next, we'll need to set the `power_scheme` value to `1`, otherwise the `power_save` mode will be reset with every reboot.
3. Add/Modify this line to the same file, ensuring the value is `1`:

   ```
   options iwlmvm power_scheme=1
   ```
4. Reboot

   A reboot is not entirely necessary, as disabling and re-enabling wireless will do the same job, but a reboot will generally ensure any "cruft" is cleared out ahead of time.

That's all there is to it. Once these two changes are made, the wireless card will never *completely* shut down unless you put the computer into airplane mode or disable the wireless device. This does result in a higher power draw when the computer is locked or suspended, but it does tend to be worth the perceived cost.

Hope this solves your issue

Comment: Since yesterday evening I haven't had the issue, so I guess this is the solution :)
It won't disturb other things, like hibernation, right?

Comment: No, this should not at all interfere with hibernation as that's a superseding command set.

Comment: Bad news :( apparently after 20-30 minutes the problem happens again...